# JBoss EAP 7.3 Error while trying to locate WSL

Tags: web-services, jboss

I am trying to deploy a basic web service, my wsdl is located as shown in the following beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

        <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

        <jaxws:endpoint 
          id="helloWorld" 
          implementor="com.tsdevelopment.HelloWorldImpl" 
      wsdlLocation="src/main/resources/wsdl/HelloWorld.wsdl"
          address="/HelloWorld" />
          
</beans>
```

When i deploy with mvn wildfly:deploy i get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\codereadystudio\jboss-eap-7.3\bin\src\main\resources\wsdl\HelloWorld.wsdl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:189)
    at org.apache.xerces@2.12.0.SP02-redhat-00001//org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1009)
    at org.apache.xerces@2.12.0.SP02-redhat-00001//org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:144)
    at org.apache.xerces@2.12.0.SP02-redhat-00001//org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:832)
    at org.apache.xerces@2.12.0.SP02-redhat-00001//org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:798)
    at org.apache.xerces@2.12.0.SP02-redhat-00001//org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.xerces@2.12.0.SP02-redhat-00001//org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.xerces@2.12.0.SP02-redhat-00001//org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:298)
    at deployment.soap-cxf-wsdlfirst-jbosseap73-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188)
    ... 56 more
```

Why is it searching for the WSDL in the jboss installation folder and not in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the reason that it was unable to find the WSDL was that while in pom.xml the wsdl paths were as following:

```
<wsdlOptions>
  <wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>
      src/main/resources/wsdl/HelloWorld.wsdl
    </wsdl>                                      
    <wsdlLocation>wsdl/HelloWorld.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
  </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```

The java class that the cxf cxf-codegen-plugin generated did not include the wsdlLocation parameter in the @WebService annotation. Also please note that the parameter path must contain only the folders under your build path. That said, while my pom.xml location was /src/main/resources/wsdl/HelloWorld.wsdl, my parameter was wsdl/HelloWorld.wsdl, because i had already included the /src/main/resources folder on the build path.